# Extract hive count string using regex

Tags: regex, hive, beeline

I am trying to get total number of records in a hive table using paramiko. I know we can use Pyhive or pyhs2 but it requires certain configuration and it will take alot of time to get that done from my IT team.

So I am using paramiko to execute the below command and get count:

```
beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000 -n hive -e 'select count(*) from table_name'
```

And i get following result,

```
+----------+--+
|   _c0    |
+----------+--+
| 1232322  |
+----------+--+
```

I need to extract this count from the output.

I have tried the following code and RE but its not working,

```
pattern="""
+----------+--+
|   _c0    |
+----------+--+
| [0-9]*   |
+----------+--+
"""

import paramiko


si, so, se=ssh_con.exec_command("beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000 -n hive -e 'select count(*) from table_name'")
print(so.read().decode())
print(re.match(pattern,so.read().decode()))
```

I am able to retrieve count and print it. Just looking for regular expression to extract count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Beeline, the result can be displayed in different formats. By default the result is being printed in a table with header. You can remove header and table, no need in parsing result using regexp. Add these options: `--showHeader=false` `--outputformat=tsv2`

```
beeline --showHeader=false --outputformat=tsv2 -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000 -n hive -e 'select count(*) from table_name'
```

Read more details about [**Output Formats**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-csv2,tsv2,dsv).

Comment: This is even better for me! Saved 5 lines of code. Awsm thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You mean to match the whole string and just extract the number below a table name.

Here is a regex that fixes your approach:

```
^\+-+\+--\+\n\| *\w+ *\|\n\+-+\+--\+\n\| *(\d+) *\|\n\+-+\+--\+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/apapWa/3). The `\w+` matches one or more word chars and matches any table name.

However, it seems all you need is a regex to match a number between `| ... |`.

Use

```
result = ''
m = re.search(r'\|\s*(\d+)\s*\|', so.read().decode()) 
if m:
    result = m.group(1)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/apapWa/2).

**Details**

- `\|` - a `|` char
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `\s*\|`  - 0+ whitespaces and a `|` char.