# How to capture row count of a table in a variable in Unix

Tags: shell, unix, hive

```
hive -e "select count (*) from table where year=2019 and month=04 and day=15"
```

This command gives me result as 15 in below format

```
+----+
| a  |
+----+
| 15 |
+----+
```

How do I get the value as just 15 instead of above format?

Comment: If you are running it using beeline, read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56634412/2700344

Answer (score 0):

the below code will be helpful for you.

```
a=$(hive -e "select count (*) from table where year=2019 and month=04 and day=15")
echo $a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hive -e "select count (*) from table where year=2019 and month=04 and day=15" | grep -o '[0-9]*'
```

The `-o` switch outputs only that part from the input, which actually corresponds to the pattern.